# Random number script producing non-random number in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the code below to generate a random number :-

```
Dim LRandomNumber   As Integer

LRandomNumber = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
```

The code was taken from https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/rnd.php

However every time I run the code in MS Access, LRandomNumber = 734.

Am I using the code incorrectly, and if not, is the a better way to generate a random number between 1 and 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Randomize` on the line before it.

Comment: Randomize() didn't work, but Randomize did - thank you. Will accept shortly.